# Can I use HttpClient in a netstandard1.0 project?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I have some cs projects that I am building into a nuget package that will be installed by another app made with PCLs. I've changed the projects to target netstandard1.0, this made the nuget installable by PCLs. I managed to resolve all references needed by the netstandard1.0 projects except System.Net.Http.  One project has to make an HTTP request out and we were using HttpClient. I cannot find a way to use HttpClient in a netstandard1.0 project. Is this possible?

Comment: According to the docs `HttpClient` is only available from **.NET Standard 1.1** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to

Comment: Yes I was trying to avoid upgrading netstandard in order for the dlls to be installed by a PCL project. The PCL is Profile78 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get around upgrading to netstandard1.1 and had to update the PCL profiles to be Profile111 to work with netstandard 1.1